# Chrome: Mixed content issue for local IP address 192.168

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sockets, printing

I have a website which is all secure content on https and am using javascript sdk for local network printer which starts with 192.168.x.x
My printer is listening on that IP address with port 8008 (http)
When my application starts printing, the printer is initialized as soemthing like this
http://192.168.199.69:8008/socket.io/1/?t=1512574905603
Chrome is blocking this request and I am not able to print. Error msg as below.

How can I tell chrome that its a local URL and make it allow to request that URL?

epos-2.6.0.js:6 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mywebsite/order-list.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://192.168.199.69:8008/socket.io/1/?t=1512574905603'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

Self signed certificates are no longer accepted...

I really don't understant why mixed content blocks ip addresses of the local network, only localhost is allowed.

That means it is not possible to create a web app (a PWA for example) and communicate with small IOT devices (there are offline and just waiting commands through HTTP).

Comment: This is exactly my issue as well. I hate to simply add a +1 comment, but I have an IoT device which I have no control over that I'm trying to use its API over my local network via its static IP address– and Chrome will not let me get any response from it at all using fetch. I can view the response if I just type it in the URL, but not from my web app where I need it. Between mixed content errors and CORS errors my motivation is just dead.

Answer (score 1):

Get a self signed certificate, upload to your service/server and there you go.
However the basic question of getting around http in a mixed content mode still remains or it won't be allowed..
Firefox adds an exception but chrome , im not sure